# Dual boot: I wanna install Ubuntu 18.04.6 along side already installed 20.04.4 but Ubuntu 18.04 installer cannot detect HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to do dual-boot setups.
I installed Ubuntu 20.04 as follows.

[image]
And it can recognise the bootable USB.
[image]

And I booted the USB.
However, there were some error messages as follows.
[image]

And when booted, I cannot use mouse except for keyboard.

[image]

Also, it didn't detect HDD as follows.

[image]

I wanna install 18.04 along side 20.04.
How can I solve this issue? Please help me...

EDIT: the System info is:

```
➜  ~ sudo dmidecode | grep -A 9 "System Information"
[sudo] password for jinrae:
System Information
        Manufacturer: HP
        Product Name: HP Laptop 17-cn0xxx
        Version:
        Serial Number: 5CG1222FQJ
        UUID: 374ace27-53d7-1948-8c46-402b17cfcdc9
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: 316H8UA#ABA
        Family: 103C_5335KV HP Notebook
```

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Or how new is system. Often you need Ubuntu version to be a year or so newer than hardware for easy install. If 20.04 works, post this from it or newer live installer. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred thx but I don't fully understand your advice. I'll edit my post to show the model info

Comment: @oldfred As you said, it may be because the model is too new. One of my colleges told me that he also encountered the same issue and he simply changed his laptop to an older one :(

Comment: why do you need 18.04 anyways? it's about to go EOL really soon

Comment: @Esther idk why but my project requires me to use 18.04

Comment: might be able to get 20.04 or 22.04 to work, if you know exactly why 18.04 is necessary.

Comment: Use a virtual machine. Problem solved.